# Connection refused for the second container in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a single deployment containing two containers and have different ports like:

```
template: {
  spec: {
   containers: [
     {
      name: container1,
      image: image1,
      command: [...],
      args: [...],
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent,
      ports: [
        {
          name: port1,
          containerPort: 80,
        },
      ],
      .............
    },
    {
      name: container2,
      image: image1,
      command: [...],
      args: [...],
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent,
      ports: [
        {
          name: port2,
          containerPort: 81,
        },
      ],
      ------------
    }

       ]
     }
  }
```

The problem I am facing is when I execute `curl -XGET <POD_IP>:80`, it is giving me the response but using `curl -XGET <POD_IP>:81` gives me `Failed to connect to <pod_ip> port 81: Connection refused`. Did I miss anything here? Also, note that both containers have identical images having different commands and args for the internal logic.

Comment: Perhaps, you need to provide more info about what `container2` is running. Like, **Is the application running on `container2` listening on port 81?**

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to make this a single pod instead of 2 pods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check container logs to see if your container is functional, seems like it is not running and the port is closed. You can log into a container as:

```
kubectl exec -ti <pod>/<container> -- bash
```

And check the logs in `/var/logs/` directory.

This is a hard to debug problem, that is why we generally only put 1 container per pod, which allow us to debug better using the Kubernetes native API abilities, like events, logs, and controllers etc :)